# Redux-thunk - dispatch is not a function

Tags: react

Olá, estou tendo problemas com o `redux-thunk`. O console me mostra o erro dizendo que o `dispatch` não está definido dentro da minha ação, Tentei dar um `console.log` dos argumentos que recebo na função e não estou recebendo nada.

O erro acontece a 5ª linha da action. Na 3ª adicionei um `console.log` que retorna `undefined`.

Código:

**Action**

```
export function signUp(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(dispatch)
    if (data.email === 'name@server.com') {
      dispatch(signIn(data, () => {
        if (data.type === '2') {
          browserHistory.push('/settings/profile')
        } else {
          browserHistory.push('/')
        }
      }))
    } else {
      return {
        type: ActionTypes.USER_SIGN_UP__ERROR
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

**mapActionsToProps**

```
const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => ({
  signUp (data) {
    console.log(dispatch)
    dispatch(userActions.signUp(data))
  }
})
```

Como você pode ver, eu imprimi no console a funcão `dispatch` dentro de  `mapActionsToProps`, e está retornando como o esperado:

```
  function (action) {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  }
```

Obrigado

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Eduardo, bem-vindo! Traduz a pergunta e coloca o texto do erro e a linha de código em que ocorreu.

Comment: Não percebo a sintaxe de `mapActionsToProps`. Podes explicar o conteúdo/objetivo dessa função?

Comment: Oi Sérgio, a mapActionsToProps é uma função que é passada para o `connect`, do `react-redux`. essa função recebe como argumento o `dispatch` para chamar o action creator. Até ai está tudo funcionando certo.

Basicamente estou chamando `dispatch(actionCreator(data))`, mas o action creator não está recebendo o `dispatch` do `redux-thunk`.

Comment: Mas quando tens `signUp(data)` e depois `{}` isso não faz sentido certo? ou invocas a função com `signUp(data)` ou declaras uma nova função com `function signUp (data) {...etc``

Comment: @Sergio, o que fiz escrito de uma forma diferente é:

`const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    signUp: (data) => {
      console.log(dispatch)
      dispatch(userActions.signUp(data))
    }
  }
})`

Comment: Mas falta `=>` no teu código, tens `signUp (data) {
    console.log(dispatch)...`

Comment: `In ECMAScript 2015, a shorthand notation is available, so that the keyword "function" is no longer necessary`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions